# Android : Get return value from DatePicker / Date Set

Tags: android

I have two buttons on my page. When a button is pressed, the dater picker dialog opens. On clicking DONE of date picker, I want to set my button text to the date user has selected.

I want to do this using a single function for datepicker.

My Code:

```
final Button fromdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonTripConfigureFrom);     
    fromdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {                   
        public void onClick(View v)
            {                           
                showDialog(0);     
                fromdate.setText(date);
            }
     });

final Button tilldate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonTripConfigureTo);       
    tilldate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {                   
        public void onClick(View v)
            {                           
                showDialog(0);  
                tilldate.setText(date);
            }
     });

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {   
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int myMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateSetListener,myYear, myMonth, myDay);
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) 
    {           
       date = day + "/" + (month+1) +"/"+ year;                    
    } 
};
```

However, when I do this the user selected value is not displayed. It is displayed only when i press the button again.(the settext of button is being executed before user presses DONE of datepicker)

All the solutions I have checked indicate modification inside dateset function. But as I have two different buttons, I cannot use settext of button inside dateset function.

Is there any way by which the value is returned by date set function or a way by which a parameter can be passed to dateset, and then using if then inside dateset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating fromdate Button only when you click on it. It is why it is updated when you click on it once more...
To update it when date is set, you have to change its text in myDateSetListener.onDateSet but as you have two button, set some value in your buttons.onClick to remember which button was clicked :

```
    mFromdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonTripConfigureFrom);     
    mFromdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {                   
        public void onClick(View v)
            {                           
                showDialog(0);
                mButtonClicked = 0;
            }
    });

    mTilldate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonTripConfigureTo);       
    mTilldate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {                   
        public void onClick(View v)
            {                           
                showDialog(0);
                mButtonClicked = 1;
            }
    });

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) 
        {         
            if(mButtonClicked == 0)
                mFromdate.setText(day + "/" + (month+1) +"/"+ year);
            else if(mButtonClicked == 1)  
                mTillDate.setText(day + "/" + (month+1) +"/"+ year);           
        } 

    };
```

Also, make mFromdate, mTilldate and mButtonclicked fields of your class ;)

Answer (score 0):

All I can think as of now is:-

```
static int buttonClicked;    
final Button fromdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonTripConfigureFrom);     
        fromdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {                   
            public void onClick(View v)
                {      
                    buttonClicked = fromDate.getId();
                    showDialog(0);
                }
         });

final Button tilldate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ButtonTripConfigureTo);       
    tilldate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {                   
        public void onClick(View v)
            {        
                buttonClicked = tillDate.getId();                   
                showDialog(0);
            }
     });

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {   
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int myMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateSetListener,myYear, myMonth, myDay);
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) 
    {           
       date = day + "/" + (month+1) +"/"+ year; 
       Button btn = (Button) dialog. findViewById(buttonClicked);  //assuming the dialog in which the button is a class level variable.. 
       btn.setText(date);                   
    } 
};
```

this should definitely do it. :)

EDIT- What I did to your code is that I stored the id of the button that was pressed. Then retrieved the button from this stored id in onDateSet() method and set the selected date as the text of that Button..

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Your solution is quite good as it removes the if clause, but it won't work for me as the two buttons are inside a dialog.

Comment: Inside the dialog means which dialog?? Can u post a screenshot or something??